# PHP MySQL query to selecting available room in hotel booking system

Tags: php, mysql, sql

currently I'm doing project for hotel booking system. Which is providing self-check-in system to user and it generates room number randomly based on `roomtype` selected. It sounds my project quiet weird for me but my supervisor gives me the idea to do so.

So far i've done the self check-in system and randomly generate room number

Now i'm confused in selecting available room

here is the table of `room` provided

`dor` is date of reservation or checkin date

`dco` is checkout date

```
room_num     roomtype     dor            dco
  101         Single    0000-00-00    0000-00-00
  102         Single    2014-05-29    2014-05-31
  103         Single    0000-00-00    0000-00-00
  111         Deluxe    0000-00-00    0000-00-00
  112         Deluxe    0000-00-00    0000-00-00
  113         Deluxe    2000-00-00    0000-00-00
  114         Deluxe    2014-06-01    2014-06-06
  115         Deluxe    0000-00-00    0000-00-00
  116         Deluxe    2014-06-08    2014-06-11
  121         Superior  0000-00-00    0000-00-00
  122         Superior  0000-00-00    0000-00-00
```

`0000-00-00` means the room number not yet selected by the system. Because the `room_num` selected randomly by system

and below is the table `room_booked`. All data below comes from SQL update trigger from `rooms` table

```
room_num     roomtype     dor           dco
  102         Single    2014-05-29    2014-05-31
  114         Deluxe    2014-06-01    2014-06-06
  116         Deluxe    2014-06-08    2014-06-11
```

now what's the SQL code to select the available room number from `room` table, based on selected `roomtype`. Which is not at the between checkin date and checkout date mentioned on `room_booked`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything, researched this, Google? All we see are table structures with no attempt. In your case, you need to use a [`WHERE()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm) clause.

Comment: WHERE $date NOT BETWEEN dor AND dco. $date is current date

Comment: `room_booked` data is came from trigger after update in `room` table. There is a possibility that the system selected the same room with different `dor` and `dco` and the `room_booked` table used to store room number and booked date

Comment: Search for SQL date overlapping queries.

Comment: don't use `0000-00-00` for unknown dates. an sql null would be a far better option. `0000-00-00`, while not exactly obvious. is still a "valid" date as far as mysql's concerned.

Comment: I would go as far as there should never be a date set to zeros to identify a room being empty.  You should have a totally seperate column for that.  Then you can leave the dates in there to see when the room was last made available - which is actually more correct.

Comment: You have duplicated data in the database. It's not good. In my opinion the reservations dates have nothing to do with the main room information and the room type should not be contained in the table of the booked rooms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've already said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834525/php-mysql-query-to-selecting-available-room-in-hotel-booking-system#comment36674567_23834525), I would prefer another database structure. So I created the tables `room` and `room_booked` first

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS room_booked;
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS room;

CREATE TABLE room (
    room_num INT NOT NULL,
    roomtype ENUM('Single', 'Deluxe', 'Superior') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (room_num)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE room_booked(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    room_num INT NOT NULL,
    dor DATE NOT NULL,
    dco DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (room_num) REFERENCES room(room_num)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and filled them with your original data

```
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (101, 'Single');
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (102, 'Single');
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (103, 'Single');
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (111, 'Deluxe');
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (112, 'Deluxe');
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (113, 'Deluxe');
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (114, 'Deluxe');
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (115, 'Deluxe');
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (116, 'Deluxe');
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (121, 'Superior');
INSERT INTO room (room_num, roomtype) VALUES (122, 'Superior');

INSERT INTO room_booked (id, room_num, dor, dco) VALUES (1, 102, '2014-05-29', '2014-05-31');
INSERT INTO room_booked (id, room_num, dor, dco) VALUES (2, 114, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-06');
INSERT INTO room_booked (id, room_num, dor, dco) VALUES (3, 116, '2014-06-08', '2014-06-11');
```

Now the `SELECT` statement. In this example the user wants to book a `Deluxe` room at `2014-06-01`.

```
SELECT
    room_num, roomtype
FROM
    room
WHERE
    room_num NOT IN (
        SELECT
            room.room_num
        FROM
            room
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            room_booked ON room_booked.room_num = room.room_num
        WHERE
            -- room type
            roomtype != 'Deluxe'
            OR (
                -- wished booking date is after or at the DOR date
                '2014-06-01' >= dor
                -- OR wished booking date is before the DCO date
                AND '2014-06-01' <  dco
            )
    )
ORDER BY
    RAND()
LIMIT 0, 1
;
```

If you only take the part before `ORDER BY`, you'll get a list of the `Deluxe` rooms available at `2014-06-01`.

Comment: does `2014-06-01` is the checkin date that selected by guest?

Comment: Yes. In this example the user wants to book a `Deluxe` room at `2014-06-01`.

Comment: I've just edited the answer. I think, it makes sense to use `>=` instead of `>` in the `WHERE` condition `'2014-06-01' >  dco`. Because usually, when the gues checks out, the room can be used/booked at the same day.

Comment: I just tested in this case. All deluxe room filled up from August 1 to August 6. Then, three of deluxe has been booked in June, as well as checked out in June. I tried your code by selecting date range from August 1 to 6. However, it shows the room number that has been booked in June instead of 0 or fully booked

Comment: OK, I have reproduced the error. Please wait a moment, I'm fixing it.
The problem is the `LEFT JOIN` -- it considers all entries of the table `room` and for every one also one erty from the table `room_booked`. So, a situation can occur, when for one room there are multiple entries in `room_booked` and only one of them is considered. E.g. `id=4 dor=2014-05-25 dco=2014-08-30` and `id=5 dor=2014-04-01 dco=2014-04-03` for room `115`. When only the last one is considered, a request `SELECT ... WHERE '2014-06-01' < dor OR '2014-06-01' >=  dco` will also return this (actually booked) room.

Comment: I've fixed the bug. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ROOM_NUM
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE roomtype=varRoomType AND
      dor=0000-00-00
```

Now I think TOP 1 is a mysql thing if your using oracle I think you have to add a rownumber=1 to the where clause. But this should get you the first found open room that matches a certain room type.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT room_num 
from room 
where roomtype = $roomtype 
and $room_booked 
not between dor and dco
```

That should grab any rooms that are not currently booked between those two dates.

Comment: Most likely `$room_booked` will actually be two dates: checkin and checkout.

Comment: what is the $room_booked, is that something like selecting columns from room booked or something else?

Comment: $room_booked is a parameter that is passed in to the query.  Presumably it will be in date format.  You'd have to populate that in your PHP on the way in.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your problem statement is that, you need SQL statement which will provide all currently available room for booking.

There could be two solutions for this

**Solution 1**

```
SELECT
    room_num
FROM
    room
WHERE
    room_num NOT IN(SELECT room_num FROM room_booked)
    AND roomtype = {ROOMTYPE}
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

**Solution 2**

```
SELECT
    room_num
FROM
    room
WHERE
    dor != '0000-00-00' AND dco != '0000-00-00'
    AND roomtype = {ROOMTYPE}
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the room randomly and you will give the room type in mysql you can use this query

```
SELECT * FROM room where roomtype='your_given_room_type' and dor='0000-00-00' and dco='0000-00-00' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

So it will pick one random room from the available rooms